# How to add new document in the solr server using ajax

Tags: jquery, solr

I am trying to add new document in the solr server using ajax.

To add a new document in the solr server we have to write 
http:// 192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true%20-H%20%22Content-Type:%20text/xml%22%20--data-binary%20%20%3Cadd%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cfield%20name='id'%3E19990%3C/field%3E%3C/doc%3E%3C/add%3E

actual Code:
< add>< doc> < field name='id>19990>< /field> < /doc> < /add>

Now i tried to add the document in the server .

My AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true%20-H%20%22Content-Type:%20text/xml%22%20--data-binary%20'<add><response><doc><field%20name='id'>19990</field></doc></response></add>'",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
            }
        });
```

ajax call didn't show any error.

then i try to fetch the data 
like this:
 http:// 192.168.10.113:8080/solr/select/?q=19990&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

it is not showing that data.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It might take sometime till the solr repository get updated. look on your commit strategy and maybe try to commit on your own.
2. How did you tried to add it? using curl? or using some browser? cause the request might be an update or a post request...
3. use this: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr
4. the "--data-binary" is a curl flag and not should be in the url, you should put your xml data in the ajax request's data and not in the url:

> ```
>  $.ajax({
>         type     : "POST",
>         url      : "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true",
>         data     : { xml: escape("<add><response><doc><field name=id>19990</field></doc></response></add>") },
>         dataType : "text/xml",
>         success  : function(msg){
>             alert('Success ');
>         },
>         error    : function(msg) {
>             alert('Failed');
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add new data to server.I searched on Google and get that query.
My Ajax Code is
$.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true%20-H%20%22Content-Type:%20text/xml%22%20--data-binary%20'<add><response><doc><field%20name='id'>19990</field></doc></response></add>'",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                }
            });

Comment: please add you code in your original question so we can read it.

Comment: Can you please explain why you have written like this??
what is xml:escape("19990")???
Sorry as I am new to solr I don't know any thing about this.
my wrote link you gave the solution, it is showing FAILED alert message.

Comment: It's not a problem with solr, the problem is with jquery, take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .one more think- I'm not sure taht you need the escape part, it might work as a regular string.

Comment: I want to sent json object rather than XML .

how to do this.

Comment: I want to send the above jqery using json.Is it possible??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18637/discussion-between-shem-and-bhagirathi)

Comment: Hi Shem
Please Help to solve this problem
That ajax call is showing this exception.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
I tried a lot but not succeed.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples shown on the [Solr Wiki - Update XML Messages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Passing_commit_and_commitWithin_parameters_as_part_of_the_URL) page, it appears that your formatting for the add code is off. It should be the following:

```
<add><doc><field name="id">19990</field></doc></add>
```

Url encoded value:
       `%3Cadd%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cfield%20name%3D%22id%22%3E19990%3C%2Ffield%3E%3C%2Fdoc%3E%3C%2Fadd%3E`

Give that a try and see if the document get added.

Additionally, since you are using Ajax, if your data is already in a JSON format, you might want to consider sending the JSON data over. Please refer to [Solr Wiki - Update JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) for more details.

Comment: Sorry I mentioned wrongly in the question. 
Actually i added the xml written by you.
its not showing any result.

Comment: Can you add the code for your actual ajax call to add the document to the question. Also have you checked the logs for your Solr hosting container to ensure there are not any error?

Comment: My Ajax call code:
$.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true%20-H%20%22Content-Type:%20text/xml%22%20--data-binary%20'<add><response><doc><field%20name='id'>19990</field></doc></response></add>'",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                }
            });